# Concatenating a string in C and then reseparating it

Tags: c

In a C program, I'm taking 2 command line arguments and concatenating them as a single parameter to a function like this:

```
some_function(strcat(argv[1], argv[2]));
```

So, if I pass arg1 and arg2 for example the result that is passed is arg1arg2

And then, inside the function, I need to reseparate them into arg1 and arg2. I tried using strtok() function like this(with arg being concatenated string):

```
source = strtok(arg, "\\");
destination = strtok(NULL, "\\");
```

but this doesnt seem to be working, as the concatenated string, arg1arg2 is stored in source and null is stored in destination. So, how do I get it so source is arg1 and destination is arg2?

Comment: I hope `argv` is not the second `main` parameter

Comment: In first place, why don't you just pass multiple arguments? Also, the concatenation invokes UB because the destination buffer is too short.

Comment: I very much doubt that `strcat(argv[1], argv[2])` works. Probably `argv[i]` has just enough space for itself.

Comment: Agreed.  That was my first thought as well.

Comment: Also, where should the `'\\'` come from?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to your stated problem is to copy the arguments into a new array.

```
char args[strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]) + 1];
sprintf(args, "%s%s", argv[1], argv[2]);
```

Or, more traditionally:

```
char *args = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
sprintf(args, "%s%s", argv[1], argv[2]);
/* free args when you are through with it */
```

Now, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are still separated.

Comment: This is not standard C code, because it uses variable length arrays. It wont compile on a lot of compilers.

Comment: @pmr You're late by 14 years. Since 1999, C has VLAs. If a C compiler doesn't support them, one must throw it away as far as possible.

Comment: @pmr variable length arrays are Standard C, what old Standard do you have? :)

Comment: @ouah My bad. Somehow I thought I'm dealing with C++ here.

Comment: @H2CO3 C11 made VLA support optional. My personal opinion is that code that makes use of VLAs should be thrown away as far as possible.

Comment: @Praetorian: Did not realize that about C11, I have added a non-VLA alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You would save yourself a lot of troubles if you were simply providing both arguments to your function :

> some_function(argv[1], argv[2]);

then, defining one for source and the other for destination would be trivial.
And if you need the concatenated string, you can still do it *inside* the function.